# Folder Names on Start Menu then its directory

Tags: windows-server-2003, start-menu

Is there any way I can make Windows Server 2003 show the name of folder I opened on Start Menu then whole directory of it, e.g. now I got 4 folders opened and they all showing me this,

```
C:\Documents and Settings\...
```

Even though I am in different folders but I can't identify them.

Not sure if its the right place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the title bar no, there's no control (unless there's a hidden registry setting), but the address bar is a bit more intelligent at showing the more pertinent parts, and clicking in the address bar reverts back to the full path string.

Comment: problem is, I have to go through 4 of folders opened (but minimized) to see which folder is which one :(

Comment: Then an alternative might be: Launching task manager, shows the explorer windows with folder names as a list.  Alt+Tab or Win+Tab might also show the name?